# using xpath with lxml isn't returning a value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to get the header of this website (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About) by using beautiful soup and lxml's xpath.

This is the code that I'm using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests

xpath_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About"
xpath_headers = ({'User-Agent':
'Safari/537.36',\
'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
xpath_wpage = requests.get (xpath_url, headers = xpath_headers)
xpath_soup = BeautifulSoup (xpath_wpage.content, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML (str(xpath_soup))
print (dom.xpath ('//*[@id="firstHeading"]')[0].text)
```

When I run this it just prints "None" even though I'm expecting it to print "Wikipedia:About"

I've tried copying the full XPath instead of using the current one which just gives me the same result.

Comment: You have already `beautifulsoup` object, you can use CSS selector and/or `bs4` api. Or is there a reason to use `lxml`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am more familiar with xpath and to my knowledge beautifulsoup doesn't have xpath capabilities

Comment: Then you can skip the `xpath_soup = BeautifulSoup (xpath_wpage.content, "html.parser")` part and read the source directly to `lxml`. You've tagged the question with `beautifulsoup` tag, so if you wish I can write an answer with `bs4`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
from lxml import html as lh

dom = xpath_wpage.fromstring(req.text,'lxml')
print(" ".join(doc.xpath('//h1[@id="firstHeading"]//text()'))
```

Output:

```
'Wikipedia : About'
```